# Simple scan document scanner

Tags: pdf, scanner

I was scanning parts of a textbook I need to return to the library soon( & it might be months before I can borrow it again) then saved it as a PDF which wouldn't open because it was corrupted,then tried a lot of different things (saving as an image...) the only thing that worked was taking a screenshot.

When I open the program it remembers the pages I scanned but it closes every time that I try to move the orange sliding bar to see beyond the first 3 pages.Where can I find the system memory folder to try to access the program's memory & get to see the scanned pages?

Or is there a better way? I haven't restarted the PC because i think it might delete the images without saving.It took me a long time to scan & I really don't want to have to do it all over again.
(I have Kubuntu but the program works the same as when I had Ubuntu)
 Thanks!